# Wrapper method which takes interface argument and operates on sub-class

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface "I" which contains the field "ID". From that interface, I have objects A, B, C, D which implement it. In a completely separate class Database, I have 4 methods named Foo which operate on A, B, C, and D.

While writing a method for Foo which operates on a bunch of Dictionary objects containing caches of my subclasses, I noticed that I am writing the same bit of code over and over again. It looks like

```
foreach(A in ACache.Values)
{
    int ID = A.ID;
    Database.Foo(A);
    int newID = A.ID;
    Bar(A);
}
```

I have to do this for all my caches, there's about 11 total, so I am attempting to write some sort of generic method which can perform these operations. Bar operates on I, so there are no issues with that. The only problem I'm seeing is with Database.Foo, because though there are implementations of Foo for all types which implement I, writing a simple wrapper as such:

```
void FooWrapper<T>(T obj) where T: I  { Database.Foo(obj); }
```

Does not fit the bill. How can I get this to work? I would prefer to avoid using Reflection if possible.

EDIT: As requested, signature(s) of Database.Foo:

```
public bool Foo(ref A aItem); //returns true based on success of query
public bool Foo(ref B bItem); 
public bool Foo(ref C cItem);
```

EDIT2: Alright, I was able to write FooWrapper as such:

```
FooWrapper<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> fooDelegate) where T : I
{
    foreach(T item in items)
    {
        int oldId = item.ID;
        fooDelegate(item);
        int newId = item.ID;
        Bar(item);
    }
}
```

And call it as such:

```
FooWrapper(ACache.Values, (Func<A, bool>) Database.Foo);
```

This works, but I'd prefer something more elegant, are there other things I could do to avoid passing in the delegate?

Comment: Can you please provide a little more detail about your code?

Comment: please post the signature of Database.Foo()

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Dependency Injection, it would be trivial to register components implementing an interface IDatabaseDoingStuffTo with a method taking your classes into account.

```
interface IDatabaseDoingStuffTo<T>{
    void DoStuff(Database db, T t);
}
```

then in your code you would have

```
foreach(A in ACache.Values)
{
    process(db, A);
}

public void process(Database db, I i)
{
    int ID = i.ID;
    // retrieve IDatabaseDoingStuffTo
    var iddsti = retrieveDatabaseBridge(i);
    iddsti.DoStuff(db, i);
    int newID = i.ID;
    Bar(i);
}
```

The `retrieveDatabaseBridge` could come from:

- Dependency injection
- a key value map between the typeof A and an instance of the bridging class (a simple dictionary)
- configuration (mapping between types in the config file...)

So there are solutions, but we may need some more information regarding what you have currently available

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about Dependency Injection and how it might relate to my code? There is only one Database class, the only thing I need to have is to have the wrapper method operate on an object which implements I, as its implementing type, so I can call the proper instance of Database.Foo

Comment: Using DI you could resolve any class implementing the IDatabaseDoingStuffTo<> method matching the type you are currently processing. Matching would be automatic between any class and its Database transformation handler